# Unable to install Node-Inspector in Windows Terminal

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, terminal, node-inspector

I am new to NodeJS and trying to install Node-Inspector on Windows terminal. I am getting this error while installing.

```
 PS C:\Users\rahul> npm install -g node-inspector
npm WARN deprecated hawk@3.1.3: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.81.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated sntp@1.0.9: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
m/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@4.2.1: this library is no longer supported

> v8-profiler@5.7.0 preinstall C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-profiler
> node -e 'process.exit(0)'


> v8-debug@1.0.1 preinstall C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\v8-debug
> node -e 'process.exit(0)'

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-inspector.cmd
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\bin\inspector.js' -> 'C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-inspector.cmd'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-inspector.cmd
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-02T12_36_01_288Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\rahul> node-inspector
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector\bin\inspector.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I have ubuntu installed as WSL as well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try override the version currently installed: `npm install -g node-inspector --force`

Answer (score 0):

Since version 6.3, Node.js provides a built-in DevTools-based debugger which mostly deprecates Node Inspector, see e.g. this blog post to get started. The built-in debugger is developed directly by the V8/Chromium team and provides certain advanced features (e.g. long/async stack traces) that are too difficult to implement in Node Inspector.

For Node.js versions >=6.3 , just use the built-in node --inspect index.js, documentation here